# Drupal site shows frontpage instead of added content

Tags: 7

I'm restoring a client's site after they lost all information. After some trouble, we could restore their database, which now shows all tables. The problem is that, after uploading all files and connecting to the database, the page displays Drupal's default frontpage and says 'no content has been created yet'. The database contains all tables, and I'm assuming the connection is right; otherwise I'd get an error message.

Why aren't I seeing all info stored there?

Comment: what about table prefixes? have you checked them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have all of the tables, but you might not have all of the rows, perhaps. Two tables to look at: node and node_revision. See of there are rows there.

Comment: You're right!  I had not checked to see if the db was complete but it's not, those tables are empty.  I'll find out what the problem was, thank you :)